# Update commit on merge in BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

Is there any way to update a commit during merge process in a BitBucket. Particularly I'm interesting in renaming files (i.e. adding a timestamp at the beginning of the filename) with a special extension and location. I need to perform this action exactly when the 'merge' button is clicked in a BitBucket web UI. It is acceptable to do it as a separate commit rather than updating an existing one.

I've looked into implementing a bitbucket plugin and one of its interfaces ***RepositoryMergeCheck*** however I didn't find a way how I can use it to do something like this.

**UPDATE**
***why do I need this:*** in a repository we have a release folder dedicated to the upcoming release which contains release scripts, it is required to have a strict numbering for these scripts (e.g. 1-<script_name>.ext 2-<script_name>.ext) and it is also required to have unique numbers for each script. So to reduce developers workload we decided it would be a good idea to use as script numbers timestamps automatically placed to filenames of specific files during merge. Thus it will save us from number conflicts and it will guarantee that sequence of release scripts will match the merge order.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? It might help to say why you want to do this.

Comment: Well, even though it might be it, this question was preceded by a pretty long discussion which I had with my colleagues regarding this problem and we agreed that this could solve the problem, but I agree there could be other options so I will update the question with the details. Thanks.

Comment: Not surprisingly, your update may have just opened a can of worms. :) My first thought is the developers would (or should?) prefer to control the order the scripts are run in, rather than the order they are merged in. If you have 3 scripts in 1 PR, how will it know the correct order to run them? Or worse, what happens if 10 scripts are already checked in, and then someone decides that that they have a new script that needs to be run between script 5 and 6?

Comment: 1. in general yes they should control the order of scripts run,but we accept all related risks if it will be done automatically.
2. adding a timestamp to the merging scripts doesn't blocks us from numbering those scripts, e.g. if a dev have 2 scripts in a PR he/she can still number it let's say 1-<script_name> and 2-<script_name>. When a timestamp will be applied they become <timestamp>-1-<script_name> and <timestamp>-2-<script_name>, requirements are met and a developer's order within a PR is kept.
3. it is not allowed to change script order. And there have been no cases when it was needed.

Comment: In most of the cases developers only need to know that some particular script will be run before his/her script and that's it. But there are of course some risks that if a developer will rebase and get duplicate and just rename his/her own script (without manual analyzing of newly rebased scripts) and merge it, it will lead to errors since merged script in parallel do something contradicting to a script a developer wants to merge. We don't want to force developers to make such checks after rebasing, we want to have strict order of script runs on each env, to get the same errors on each env.

Comment: **Idea:** At my org, our devs all have a "hundreds" range they default to for their scripts (1100, 1200, etc) and they put all their scripts in their own hundreds, separated by 5 or 10 per script. They can all see each other's scripts that are already checked in for the upcoming release, and could slide a script into another dev's 100s range if it must go before/after a specific script. It's rare that this is needed, but it's super easy when it is. The tool that runs these scripts simply runs all new/changed scripts since the last run, and sorts by name (automatically number then text).

Comment: Thanks for the idea, however I'm not sure this fits our needs since we want these scripts to be run in the same order in every env, including the dev one. But following this approach scripts will be run on dev env according to merge requests order in dev branch, but after some time when we trigger a deploy of a next env the order will be by numbers. The thing is that we don't have something like a developer space for scripts runs, they change a system's state which affects all devs, so we want to be sure all scripts across all teams will be run in an order of getting to the dev branch.

Comment: I would say the main requirement here is that once a script(1) got to the dev branch, there shouldn't be a case (on any env) when a script(2) which got to the dev branch later will be run before the script number one.

Comment: Got it. That makes sense.